# |Android 17| AlarmManager doesn´t start BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am currently trying to call a BroadCastReceiver with an AlarmManager to ouput a notification on a certain time! On Android SDK Level 19+ my method works, but on Android 17 my approach leads into nothing!

There are no errors outputted, nor are there any logs in the monitor of Android Studio. The BroadcastReceiver is simply not called by the AlarmManager.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setNotification();
            }
        });
    }

    public void setNotification() {
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationPublisher.class);

        resultIntent.setData(Uri.parse("notification://1995-" + System.currentTimeMillis()));

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    this,
                    1995,
                    resultIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 30 * 1000, resultPendingIntent);
        Log.d("Test", "Alarm started");
    }
}
```

NotificationPublisher.java

```
public class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "What", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

AndroidManifext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="nbaye.apptesting">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".NotificationPublisher"
            android:process=":remote"
            android:enabled="true" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Min SDK: 17
Target: 23

EDIT: 
I have looked into the AlarmManager with "adb shell dumpsys alarm":
The alarm is created by the app, but the "when" variable of the alarm is counting down from +30 seconds to an infinite negative number!

Comment: here is an answer from 2014. Maybe it can help with your purpose: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26260759/2074990

Comment: @bofredo unfortunately it had no effect!